# You walked for hours before finding me

Tags: riddle

> You walked for hours before finding me
>
> But when you found me, you didn't want me
>
> You took me out and left me for dead on the side of the trail
>
> You kept walking... only to find me again further on

What am I?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not anywhere else on Puzzling, it's original, it has a valid answer... I apologize, I don't know exactly how this SE works

Comment: Maybe because it's too broad. I have a couple of answers myself which loosely fit. Edit: I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Well you could post them and maybe one would be right? Some of the highest voted riddles on Puzzling have multiple valid answers.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Also, are riddles not meant to be vague? If there was only one valid answer it wouldn't be as hard to get the right one

Comment: It's a rule on Puzzling that puzzles should have a single correct answer, otherwise things turn into a guessing game. One constant problem we face is that puzzles violating this rule usually get lots of answers, reach Hot Network Questions and get lots of upvotes as a result. If you want to debate this, you're welcome to do it on meta; I'm just stating the current state of things.

Comment: @ffao I understand what you're saying and I believe you. The thing is, even though some answers *almost* work, there's only one that *fully* fits the riddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer could be:

> A twig

You walked for hours to find me / before finding me:

> You needed to find some shade on a hike

But when you found me you didn't want me:

> It got caught in your shoe and irritated your foot

You took me out and left me for dead on the side of the trail:

> You removed the annoying twig, which was dead - it had fallen off the tree

You kept walking, only to find me further on

> You had entered a forest, so there were twigs everywhere

Comment: This is the correct answer, except that "You needed to find some shade on a hike" is incorrect, the hiker didn't necessarily *look* for the twig. I'd prefer that you correct that but I'll accept it as it's the right answer.

Comment: @mdxf :( im sad

Comment: @MDXF What was your intended reason for calling the puzzle 'You walked for hours to find me? That was the only reason I put the shade bit in.

Comment: I'd messed up on the meaning but not corrected the title, sorry, fixing that now... it was just to hint at a hike

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the most "tasty" answer:

> Blisters

You walked for hours and finally found me.

> On your feet

But when you found me, you didn't want me.

> You're not happy with blisters when walking long distances

You took me out and left me for dead on the side of the trail

> Used a needle to puncture the blister and sqeezed the fluid out of it

You kept walking... only to find me again further on.

> After you have got your first blister, another one might follow soon.

Comment: A good, valid answer, but not the correct one, sorry. Also, I'm new to puzzling so should a valid answer should be accepted even if it's not the intended one? A supporting help or meta link would be proof.

Comment: @MDXF You needn't accept it. More people are going to answer. You must wait.

Comment: @Meta45 +1 for the thoughtful answer but people don't want to find it. His clue *finally found me* might indicate joy or willingness to find it :)

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Oops...

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

> little rocks

You walked for hours and finally found me.

> in your shoe

But when you found me, you didn't want me.

> rocks hurt you

You took me out and left me for dead on the side of the trail

> Throw it away

You kept walking... only to find me again further on.

> another stone

Comment: To be honest, this was the answer I was originally going for... before I realized there was a better solution (not yet posted). +1

Comment: @MDXF soo.... not valid¿? lol I thought about that situation happening. writting a riddle and found an answer which fits better than the origial idea. I even imagined a hidden field only accesible after the validation answer that shows your expected solution. what are you going to do¿

Comment: Sorry about your dilemma. I'm going to wait for someone to post the more accurate solution. I'm not going to give any hints as to why it's less accurate than the better answer but this is very close.

Answer (score 4):

You could be talking about

> sweat

You walked for hours before finding me

> A strenuous activity like walking for hours will definitely make us sweat.

But when you found me, you didn't want me

> Being sweaty is uncomfortable, so we wipe it off our face and arms as best we can.

You took me out and left me for dead on the side of the trail

> We can get rid of the sweat drops by running our hands across the sweaty part of the body and letting the drops fall to the ground, where they will evaporate (or die, in a sense).

You kept walking... only to find me again further on

> If we continue walking, we will inevitably sweat more.

Comment: Not a bad answer but I upvoted before I realized it has a couple flaws: One would not 'take out' sweat. Also, it does not take hours before one would sweat; 30 minutes would be quite enough in the right conditions

Comment: @MDXF it is common practice to avoid using the answer in the comments. The whole purpose of hiding the answer is defeated. Use *it*, *your answer* or anything that doesn't reveal the answer :)

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Honestly, I just didn't want to get grief/downvotes for not accepting a valid answer

Comment: @MDXF I mean you shouldn't use the answer (i.e sweat in this case). Check out the first comment of this post.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal I didn't even hint at the answer, I simply explained why it was wrong

Comment: My bad. I just realised that you didn't explicitly use the answer in the comment anywhere else. You were just explaining :)